# Ajax database in Joomla

Tags: ajax, joomla, joomla1.5

How can I implement this script found on w3schools in Joomla 1.5? [Ajax Database](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp)

I tried to make it work for Joomla and I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /component/virtuemart/getcustomer.asp was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is complaining that it cannot find the file `/component/virtuemart/getcustomer.asp`, if you check the code it is referenced on the bottom:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?q="+str,true);
```

So you need to add the server page as well. However the code given in that example (under the title "The AJAX Server Page") is ASP code so it won't work(unless your server both supports ASP & PHP, very unlikely).

In short that example won't work for you. You need to check the other example:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

You need to add both the html page & php page.